# android studio ListView is Not populating existing listView items, which are saved in SQlite

Tags: android, listview

updated my code. My issue happens when i back out of the activity. Listview items are lost. I checked the Sqlite database and all items are saved, just not showing up again on listView when I reStart-Activity.

MainActivity

```
private ListView lst;
private CustomeAdapter cv;
private EditText nameEd, middleEd, lastEd;
private ArrayList<People> peopleArrayList;
private DataHelper myData;

peopleArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

 OnCreate.....

 public void addPerosn(View view) {

    String myName = nameed.getText().toString();
    String myMiddle = middleed.getText().toString();
    String myLast = lasted.getText().toString();


    boolean insert = myData.addData(myName, myMiddle, myLast);

    if (insert == true) {
        peopleArrayList.add(new People(myName, myMiddle, myLast));
        cv = new CustomeAdapter(this, peopleArrayList);
        lst.setAdapter(cv);
        nameed.setText("");
        middleed.setText("");
        lasted.setText("");

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

}
```

My DataHelper method i want to call to Show All

```
 public Cursor showData(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
    return data;
}
```

Any suggestions are appreciated . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have overridden `getCount` and it returns proper count.

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.length;
}
```

Apart from above solution, I would recomment you to do it in proper way

a) Create a model/pojo class say Person which will have firstName,lastName and middleName

b) create a data set of Person, i.e list of person

c) create a method addPerson in adapter class, and call whenever you want to add new Person data into the list. addPerson method will also refresh the adapter by calling `notifyDataSetChanged`

d) In activity create adapter object only once, later on just use method of it say adapter.addPerson(person)

Comment: adding the override method didn't work. and thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: What count does return method getCount, did you check that ? Whatever getCount method return that many time adapter getView method will get called.

Comment: I updated my code, did what you suggested. Now I just lose the listview items when i back out of activity and re_start it. any suggestions?

Comment: Please accept the answer or vote it as somehow it helped you, to fix the issue that you are facing now is "Create an instance variable of your adapter and initialize that first with empty list, later on somewhere in activity for example from activity onCreate method execute an asyncTask to fetch out all the rows of people table and prepare a list of People, once it is done, pass this fetched people list to the adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged". It will solve the issue.

Comment: Your adapter class should have method addPeople(People people), setPeoples(List<People> peoples) and both method should call notifyDataSetChanged internally after data set update. by doing so you need to create adapter object once in your activity and to update adapter contents just need to use these setters method accordingly your needs.

Comment: @Mora your problem get resolved ? if yes please vote up, so that no one need to work on the same.